# c++ programming on iPad

Tags: c++, ios, ipad

I am not an apple programmer but i am developing cross platform c++ application and I now need to port it to Apple devices. Do I really need to use XCode and Mac or I can buy iPad and do c++ porting compilation and testing on single iPad?

Answer (score 1):

You must have a Mac and Xcode to test your apps on iOS devices.